# Cannot curl Kubernetes service IP from the host

Tags: docker, curl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am having the same problem as mentioned here: [Cannot access kubernetes service via outside network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778956/cannot-access-kubernetes-service-via-outside-network). I have tried the solution mentioned using Ingress, but without any success.

My pods are up and running, along with my service.

I can curl any of the endpoints successfully from within a pod, but not able to curl from the host.

When I am using Ingress, the `address` field shows blank, and while trying to curl the hostname, it shows `Could not resolve host`.

I am using Kubernetes on Docker Edge, on a MacBook Pro.

How do I curl the service endpoint from the host?

Comment: What's your service type?

Comment: run kubectl get po  -o wide, you will get the ip of your pods, try to curl to them directly and let me now what happens

Comment: @suren: NodePort

Comment: @elia: I get the following:
HDMACINT18:~ dghosh$ curl 10.1.0.66 .  <-- one of the pod IP that I obtained from `kubectl get po -o wide`
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument
HDMACINT18:~ dghosh$ curl 10.1.0.66:9000 .  <-- including the port
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument
HDMACINT18:~ dghosh$ curl 10.96.60.151:9000 .    <-- service IP
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument

Comment: are you doing this from inside the cluster (are you using one of the nodes to execute curl)?  if yes it's Ip tables error

Comment: @elia: Yes (most probably)! In my case, there is only 1 node, i.e., my macbook.
[`kubectl get nodes` gives: 
`NAME                 STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION \n
docker-for-desktop   Ready     master    7d        v1.10.3`] There is no command as `iptables` in MacOS. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) on MacOS runs separate virtual machine
to run [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers and Kubernetes as well. It is important to
understand that you can have a problem connecting from MacOS to some Kubernetes
resources. TCP connections are not realized in the same way they are in the cloud environment.
It depends on the configuration of the internetworking between MacOS and the VM where Kubernetes stack
is running.
(NAT, bridge, host only connection)

I suppose that you chose a [NodePort Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) and in this kind of configuration,
you need to know both: the IP address of a node and the port where Kubernetes started to listen to
the incoming connection. Ingress, in this case, analyses a host http header to determine
a route of the traffic. It’s similar to the Service created on type:NodePort. You need to call
a proper Ingress service. It is not obvious that service is listening on Well-Known Port.
In fact, It is a bit tricky, and it may not be easy to connect from MacOS  to type:NodePort service
without knowing where did Kubernetes create a listening socket, and be sure that MacOS is actually
supporting routes to this TCP port from MacOS to VM.